# Runtime cost of creating new struct with update syntax in Rust

Tags: struct, rust, compiler-optimization

The Rust book explains how the [struct update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/book/structs.html#update-syntax) can be used to create a copy of a struct with just a few fields updated.

```
let mut point = Point3d { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
point = Point3d { y: 1, .. point };
```

It doesn't have to be the same struct either, one can use this syntax when making new ones.

```
let origin = Point3d { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
let point = Point3d { y: 1, .. origin };
```

My question is regarding the second example.

1. If the `origin` point never would be used again, will the  compiler still make an expensive (if the fields are large) copy of (almost) all the fields, or will it only update the updated fields in place and be equivalent to the first example?
2. In case it updates in place: how does the compiler can find out whether it can overwrite `origin` value?

Comment: second example is supposed to read `.. origin` ?

Comment: The Rust compiler delegates code optimization to LLVM. You probably need to add LLVM tag to get an answer faster.

Comment: I see no reason why this should not be optimized when possible. But your second case, I don't see what optimization you want.

Answer (score 10):

To answer questions such as “Does the compiler optimize this?”, I recommend looking at the disassembly. If I compile on compiler explorer with optimization on (`-O`) the following:

```
pub struct P {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

pub fn f() -> P {
    let mut point = P { x: 43, y: 12 };
    point = P { y: 1, ..point };
    point
}
```

I get:

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
movabs rax, 4294967339
pop rbp
ret
```

If you know a little bit of assembly, you can see that there is no intermediate variable created or copy made. You can add extra steps to the initialization of the return value and the output assembly shouldn't change.

If you remove optimization (I won't show assembly here), you can see in the assembly that the compiler generates a first `Point { x: 43, y: 12 }` then creates a new one by copying `x` and initializing `y` to 1.

To sum up:

- The compiler generates the logic you write: Create a point then create another one by moving (i.e. copying for simple types such as `i32`) some of the data from the first one.
- The optimizer detects that the first point is not needed and optimizes it away.

Comment: In that example, the compiler has simply optimised away the entire method because it can compute the result at compile time. The magic number being written to 'rax' is the precomputed result.

Comment: @JamesDavies Indeed, but the point is that the compiler can optimize away the copies since they don’t produce any side effects. If you think it would make the answer clearer or more complete, please edit it so that it does not depend on hard coded values. https://godbolt.org/z/Tr55nb77b

Answer (score 3):

Please note that you are linking to the *first* edition of the Rust book, specifically a version of it that is almost *2 years old* at this point. Your link is to the docs for version 1.6.0 but 1.23.0 is the current version. The [second edition of the book has different phrasing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax).

> The Rust book explains how the struct update syntax can be used to create a copy of a struct

There's nothing special about the update syntax. This example code only creates a copy because the struct members (`i32`, in this case) all implement `Copy`.

> If the origin point never would be used again, will the compiler still make a [...] copy of [...] the fields

It all depends on whether the values of the struct implement `Copy`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Coord;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point3d { x: Coord, y: Coord, z: Coord }

fn main() {
    let origin = Point3d { x: Coord, y: Coord, z: Coord };
    let point = Point3d { y: Coord, ..origin };

    println!("{:?}", origin);
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `origin`
  --> src/main.rs:15:22
   |
13 |     let point = Point3d { y: Coord, ..origin };
   |                                       ------ value moved here
14 |     
15 |     println!("{:?}", origin);
   |                      ^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `origin.x` has type `Coord`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Values will be moved unless they implement `Copy`. `Copy` indicates that the compiler should feel free to copy the bits of a type around as frequently as it likes: there are no side effects, it's efficient to do so, and it's semantically correct.

If a value is moved (i.e. doesn't implement `Copy`), then you will not be able to use it afterwards.

> It doesn't have to be the same struct either, one can use this syntax when making new ones.

You *are* making a new struct in both cases. It just so happens that in the first case you happen to have a mutable binding that you are putting it back into. It's effectively equivalent to:

```
let point = Point3d { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
let point = Point3d { y: 1, ..point };
```

Answer (score 1):

**YMMV**<sup>1</sup>

There is, in general, no *certainty* about the result of the optimizer. The semantics of the language may place some algorithmic bounds, however whether no copy, a single copy or three copies occur very much depends on the particular of the situation.

**Semantics**

Rust *moves* by default, therefore no deep-copy of the data will ever take place without a `.clone()` in the source code.

On the other hand, the number of bitwise copies is unspecified, and may vary.

**Optimization**

Optimizing compilers (from then on, optimizers) operate under the as-if rule. Each language specifies a set of *observable behaviors* and the compiler must produce code which will have the same observable behavior as a naive program. Observable behavior typically include I/O, but disregards CPU cycles and memory accesses.

The optimizer has various tricks up its sleeve:

- it does not need to materialize a struct, it can just manipulate the fields,
- it does not need to *copy* a struct or field, if two variables refer to the same value then a single value need exist,
- it does not need to materialize a value that is never read again,
- it does not need to put into memory what can be kept into a register,
- ...

So, what happen in your cases? **Nothing**.

Since you are not *using* the `Point`, they need not exist.

<sup>1</sup> *Your Mileage May Vary, a colloquial expression meaning that your experience may vary from that of others, in general because your situation is slightly different.*